# Instructions loading into registers

Tags: opcode, instructions, cpu-registers

In Instruction Set Architecture, are all kinds of instructions R- Type, I- Type, J-Type loaded into the same General Purpose Register or different kinds of instructions loaded into different registers based on the opCodes ? If different registers, then How does processor know which instruction to load to which register ? and In the design of compilers are the number of registers allowed to be loaded with instructions fixed ?

How does the processor differentiate the different types of instructions R- Type, I- Type, J-Type , is it based on the first initial opcodes ?

Answer (score 1):

> In Instruction Set Architecture, are all kinds of instructions R- Type, I- Type, J-Type loaded into the same General Purpose Register or different kinds of instructions loaded into different registers based on the opCodes ?

You seem confused.  Instructions aren't loaded into registers (unless you're writing, maybe, a disassembler).  Instructions are processed and executed -- which may cause other data to be copied into or out of registers.

> If different registers, then How does processor know which instruction to load to which register ? and In the design of compilers are the number of registers allowed to be loaded with instructions fixed ?

Not sure what you mean here.

> How does the processor differentiate the different types of instructions R- Type, I- Type, J-Type , is it based on the first initial opcodes ?

The distinction between R/I/J (this seems to be a MIPS convention?) seems somewhat arbitrary.  In many architectures they can't be so neatly divided.  Every instruction is [decoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle#2._Decode_the_instruction), and it may involve loading from memory, loading from an immediate, or changing the PC.

Comment: Yes, the question was a bit confusing, apologize for that. So what is the difference between data and instructions ? where are instructions stored ? and are data and instructions stored seperately in main memory ?